# Find the vertical asymptotes of the graph $(\!{\rm C}\!)$ of the function $y= \frac{1}{x\,\sin\frac{1}{x}}$ .

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification, trigonometry, graphing-functions

***Problem.*** *Find the vertical asymptotes of the graph* $(\!{\rm C}\!)$ *of the function* $y= \dfrac{1}{x\,\sin\frac{1}{x}}$ *.*

***Solution.*** All the solutions of the equation $x\,\sin\dfrac{1}{x}= 0$ are $x= 0$ or $x= \dfrac{1}{w\pi}\,(\!w\in \mathbb{Z}\!)$ .

Therefore, we can see that the possible vertical asymptotes are $x= 0$ or $x= \dfrac{1}{w\pi}\,(\!w\in \mathbb{Z}\!)$ .

The line $x= 0$ cannot be a vertical asymptote of $(\!{\rm C}\!)$. Consider the following sequence $x_{n}= \dfrac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}+ 2\,n\pi}$. This sequence tends to $0^{\!+}$, and the corresponding sequence
$$y_{n}= \frac{\frac{\pi}{2}+ 2\,n\pi}{\sin\left ( \dfrac{\pi}{2}+ 2\,n\pi \right )}\rightarrow +\!\infty$$
On the other hand, if we choose $x_{n}= \dfrac{1}{\frac{-\!\pi}{2}\!+\!2\,n\pi}$, which also tends to $0^{\!+}$, the corresponding sequence
$$y_{n}= \frac{- \frac{\pi}{2}+ 2\,n\pi}{\sin\left ( - \dfrac{\pi}{2}+ 2\,n\pi \right )}\rightarrow -\!\infty$$
Hence the limit does not exist when $x$ tends to $0$ on the right. Similarly for the left. Now we prove that all the remain lines are actually the vertical asymptotes of the graph $(\!{\rm C}\!)$ .

Let consider the case $x= \dfrac{1}{\pi}$. We have
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \left ( \dfrac{1}{\pi} \right )^{\!+}} y= \lim_{x\rightarrow \left ( \dfrac{1}{\pi} \right )^{\!+}} \frac{\pi}{\sin \left ( \dfrac{1}{x} \right )}\rightarrow +\!\infty$$
Notice that the denominator tends to $0$ but is always positive and therefore the limit is positive infinity. Similarly for the others vertical lines. In conclusion, all the vertical asymptotes of $(\!{\rm C}\!)$ are
$$x= \dfrac{1}{w\pi}\,(\!w\in \mathbb{Z}\!)$$
*I have a solution, and I'm looking forward to seeing a nicer one(s), thanks for your interests a lot !*

Comment: You've got a funny mistake: it's not $\pi \in \mathbb Z$ (that you write), but rather $w \in \mathbb Z$ (which I would replace, for notational elegance, by either $\omega$, or $n$).

Comment: @AlexM. I thank you a real lot !

Comment: You had made that mistake in two more places, at the top. While fixing them, I got scared by your abuse of `\!`: it doesn't add almost anything, so you'd better drop it from the formatting of your future questions. Plus, it makes your LaTeX code more difficult to read by other users.

Comment: OK! I will notice that, thanks for your interest a real lot !

Comment: @AlexM. But $(\!{\rm C}\!)$ looks nicer than $({\rm C})$ ! ! !

Comment: Allow me to write $(\!{\rm C}\!)$ instead ! Thank you so !

Comment: Surely you mean $w\in\Bbb Z$ instead of $\pi\in\Bbb Z$